# PDFMerger with FPDI-PDF-PARSER

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf, fpdi, phplib

FPDI PDF Files merger is being used. However, I ran into the following issue while trying to merge PDF files versions 1.5 and higher. The following was the error I received:

> This document (doc.pdf) probably uses a compression technique which is
>   not supported by the free parser shipped with FPDI. (See
>   https://www.setasign.com/fpdi-pdf-parser for more details)

I proceeded to visit the link, which advised to use the commercial addon **fpdi-pdf-parser**. This file is already included with the rest of the files. And in the installation steps, it is said that there are no other steps that are needed to be made, but I am still getting the same error.

It is worth noting that I am using the following PDF merger (which, in turn, uses the FPDI lib)

https://github.com/myokyawhtun/PDFMerger/blob/master/PDFMerger.php

I am not sure how I can use this "fpdi-pdf-parser addon", which is advertised to be a solution to my PDF 1.5 issue. What am I missing?

Comment: open you pdf file with text editor and paste the content here.

Comment: @anwerjunaid The content of the pdf file is irrelevant as my problem is with the multiple pdf files regardless the content to be merged together using PDFMerger.

Comment: not the contents, you may need yo check binary part of files. there are different ways how pdf can be generated.

Comment: There is example of compressed pdfs in the official document
https://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi-pdf-parser/details/

Comment: @AgamBanga I did not find the example clear, especially that I have no php experience.

Comment: Can you paste your code?

Comment: Have you tried this https://manuals.setasign.com/fpdi-pdf-parser-manual/installation/

Comment: @AhmedGinani Yes I did, it says that there is nothing more that I need to do more than adding the addon file to the other files.

Comment: Can you upload your PDF, if it's not very personal

Comment: Unfortunately it is personal. But the pdf files I am testing are not corrupted in any way, they are only pdf 1.5 and higher. Thats it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You state that you are using PDFMerger, but looking at the [project page](https://github.com/myokyawhtun/PDFMerger) shows:

> **Support of PDF 1.5 and PDF 1.6**
>
> FPDF and FPDI libraries replaced by TCPDF with TCPDI extension and parser.

So it would appear that, specifically because they don't support PDF versions >1.4, PDFMerger no longer uses FPDF and FPDI.

To test this I [downloaded](https://github.com/myokyawhtun/PDFMerger/archive/master.zip) PDFMerger (note this includes a copy of TCPDF), slightly modified the example code, and ran it with a PDF that is marked as ***version 1.7***:

```
<?php

include 'PDFMerger.php';

$pdf = new PDFMerger;

$pdf->addPDF('43451941a.pdf', '1'); // page 1 from first file.
$pdf->addPDF('43451941b.pdf', '5'); // page 5 from second file.

$pdf->merge('browser'); // send the file to the browser.
```

The result is that in my web browser I get a PDF file of two pages, as expected.

***As far as I can tell FPDF/FPDI is not required at all!***

Simply download and use PDFMerger.

Comment: I note that PDFMerger loses the content as it treats the concatenated PDFs as image files